# Is there a common linux command which connect to a TCP port with keep-alive enabled?

Tags: linux, command-line, tcp

I would like to do a little test for verifying TCP keep-alive.
I tried to use `$ nc -l -k 9530` to listen on a 9530/tcp on server and use `telnet <server IP> 9530` to create a TCP connection.

However, output of `netstat -anto` shows

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.21:58334         10.0.1.214:9530         ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

which indicates TCP keep-alive is turned off on this socket. Is there a common linux command can create TCP connection with keep-alive enabled? It seems that both `nc` and `telnet` don't support this feature. Following is OS-level keep-alive setting:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 30
```

Thanks.

Comment: ssh turns *tcp* keepalive on by default. You can start a ssh server as a regular user, on a port >= 1024.

Comment: @user414777 want to make that an answer?

Comment: socat can enable keepalive to.